# How to import and export data from Matlab to Weka to predict class?

Tags: matlab, import, machine-learning, export, weka

This is my proposed project:
 - I have developed a classifier in Weka after some experimentation. 
 - Now I want to develop a project in Matlab which will take input
   attributes from users.
 - This input will be given to Weka after loading saved classification model.
 - Weka will predict the class for that instance.
 - Finally I want to pick this predicted class and display it on screen developed by Matlab.
Now I don't know how to import and export data from Matlab to Weka. Immediate help will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? What is your level of familiarity with Matlab and Weka?

Comment: Tried:  Things like some basic commands and some small GUI projects in Matlab. In Weka, i have developed classification models, visualised data,saving/loading models, ranking and search filters etc.

Comment: Level of familarity: Beginner in Matlab

Comment: Intermediate in Weka Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some thoughts on your problem.

- As far as i know matlab has a machine learning toolbox(haven't used it). So you can build your system entirely on matlab.
- If you want to stick with Weka and use it programmatically with Java, then you can call Java methods from matlab so as to get the classification result. For how to call java methods from matlab check [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/using-java-libraries-in-matlab.html)
- If you use Weka from GUI then you should be able to save the classification result to a file straight from GUI. Then you can load this file to matlab, retrieve the result and visualize it in matlab.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got it. One thing more I want to know is 'How can I make this project useful for normal computer users?' I mean experts can easily understand the output but I want to make project for everyone.

Comment: This is a general question i am afraid i can't answer with the amount of information you provide. You need to define what is "normal computer users" and also what your project tries to solve. Consider posting a new question defining exactly what your projects specifications are otherwise you will end up getting general answers that probably won't help you.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful effort.

Comment: If you found my post helpful consider marking it as the correct answer or upvote it. Thanks.